# How to extract base64 extension without using lib imghdr

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, base64, imghdr

I have a view that works perfectly for receiving base64 images. My problem is that in some rare cases it doesn't recognize the sent jpg image. It looks like `None`.

Looking on the internet I saw that the problem is the lib **imghdr**. I tried to use OS lib to extract the extension and even use the lib pillow, but I couldn't.

Does anyone have any tips?

Here is an example of how I use imghdr:

```py
    def get_file_extension(self, file_name, decoded_file):
        import imghdr

        extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
        if extension == "jpeg":
            extension = "jpg"

        return extension
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple utility function to extract the extension

```
def base64_ext(b64str):
    # b64str format example: 'data:image/jpeg;base64, LzlqLzRBQ...'
    fmt, imgstr = b64str.split(';base64,') 
    ext = fmt.split('/')[-1]
    return ext
```